# как переключиться на другую ветку проекта скаченного с репозитория gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

склонировал репозиторий с gitLab ветка develop пробую переключиться на ветку M-341 (она есть в gitLab) пишу в терминале git checkout M-341 выдаёт ошибку error: pathspec 'М-341' did not match any file(s) known to git
Подскажите как переключиться или скачать нужную ветку

Comment: `git branch -a` эту ветку показывает?

Comment: И в совеменном гите лучше использовать `git switch` для переключения веток https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch

Comment: Как клонировали?

Comment: @AlexeyTen git@gitlab. и дальше путь репозитория

Comment: @RomanKonoval нет к сожалению не показывает

Comment: Полную команду, пожалуйста. То что вы клонировали с гитлаба вы уже написали

Comment: @AlexeyTen git clone git@gitlab.ХХХ.хххх.ru:clients/хххх/hybris.git Auto56
коечто заменил иксами)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130443/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-ahel73).

Comment: `git remote update` запустите.